# GNOME3 - программа не запускается из меню

Tags: linux, gnome

Работаю в fedora 32 с Gnome-3. Установил (через dnf) программу gnome-latex. Она, если верить названию, специально заточена под гном. Некоторое время всё работало прекрасно. А потом она перестала запускаться из меню. Т.е. я могу запустить её из номандной строки так:

```
gnome-latex
```

Запускается и работает. Могу запустить через файл ярлыка рабочего стола:

```
gtk-launch org.gnome.gnome-latex.desktop
```

Запускается и работает. А вот если я щёлкаю по кнопке "Приложения" а в выпадающем меню выбираю эту программу, то не происходит ничего. Вообще ничего. Смотрел логи - тоже ничего не увидел.

Сам файл ярлыка, описывающий запускаемую программу (org.gnome.gnome-latex.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME LaTeX
Name[ru_RU.UTF-8]=GNOME LaTeX
X-GNOME-FullName[ru_RU.UTF-8]=GNOME LaTeX
GenericName=LaTeX Editor

Comment=Edit LaTeX documents
Comment[ru_RU.UTF-8]=Редактировать документы LaTeX
Keywords=text;tex;latex;editor;documents;
Exec=gnome-latex
Icon=gnome-latex
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;WordProcessor;Publishing;Office;
MimeType=text/x-tex;
DBusActivatable=true
Actions=new-window;new-document;
NoDisplay=false
Path=
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=false

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Name[ru_RU.UTF-8]=Открыть новое окно
Exec=gnome-latex --new-window

[Desktop Action new-document]
Name=Open a New Document
Name[ru_RU.UTF-8]=Открыть новый документ
Exec=gnome-latex --new-document
```

Ярлык расположен в ~/.local/share/applications/

Может кто-то подсказать - в какую сторону копать?

Comment: А где в Gnome 3 меню?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov Это расширение гнома (стандартное) под названием "Application Menu".